# unexpected multiple execution of mapper intended to run once

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

I tried to write a very simple job with only 1 mapper and no reducer to write some data to hbase. In the mapper I tried to simply open connection with hbase, write a few rows of data to a table and then close connection. In job driver I am using JobConf.setNumMapTasks(1); and JobConf.setNumReduceTasks(0); to specify that only 1 mapper and no reducer are to be executed. I am also setting the reducer class to IdentityReducer in jobConf. The strange behavior I am observing is that the job successfully writes the data to hbase table however after that I see in the logs it continuously tried to open connection with hbase and then closes the connection which goes on for 20-30 minutes and after the job is declared to have completed with 100% success. At the end when I check the _success file created by the dummy data I put in OutputCollector.collect(...) I see hundred of rows of dummy data when there should only be 1.
Following is the code for job driver

```
    public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
        Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create(getConf());
        ensureRequiredParametersExist(config);
        ensureOptionalParametersExist(config);

        JobConf jobConf = new JobConf(config, getClass());
        jobConf.setJobName(config.get(ETLJobConstants.ETL_JOB_NAME));
        //set map specific configuration
        jobConf.setNumMapTasks(1);
        jobConf.setMaxMapAttempts(1);
        jobConf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        jobConf.setMapperClass(SingletonMapper.class);
        jobConf.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        jobConf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        //set reducer specific configuration
        jobConf.setReducerClass(IdentityReducer.class);
        jobConf.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        jobConf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        jobConf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        jobConf.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        //set job specific configuration details like input file name etc
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(jobConf, jobConf.get(ETLJobConstants.ETL_JOB_FILE_INPUT_PATH));
        System.out.println("setting output path to : " + jobConf.get(ETLJobConstants.ETL_JOB_FILE_OUTPUT_PATH));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jobConf,
                new Path(jobConf.get(ETLJobConstants.ETL_JOB_FILE_OUTPUT_PATH)));
        JobClient.runJob(jobConf);
        return 0;
    }
```

Driver class extends Configured and implements Tool (I used the sample from definitive guide)Following is the code in my mapper class.

Following is the code in my Mapper's map method where I simply open the connection with Hbase, do some preliminary check to make sure table exists and then write the rows and close the table.

```
    public void map(LongWritable arg0, Text arg1,
        OutputCollector<LongWritable, Text> arg2, Reporter arg3)
        throws IOException {


    HTable aTable = null;
    HBaseAdmin admin = null;


    try {

        arg3.setStatus("started");

        /*
         * set-up hbase config
         */
        admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);

        /*
         * open connection to table
         */
        String tableName = conf.get(ETLJobConstants.ETL_JOB_TABLE_NAME);

        HTableDescriptor htd = new HTableDescriptor(toBytes(tableName));
        String colFamilyName = conf.get(ETLJobConstants.ETL_JOB_TABLE_COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME);

        byte[] tablename = htd.getName();
        /* call function to ensure table with 'tablename' exists */

        /*
         * loop and put the file data into the table
         */
        aTable = new HTable(conf, tableName);

        DataRow row = /* logic to generate data */
        while (row != null) {
            byte[] rowKey = toBytes(row.getRowKey());
            Put put = new Put(rowKey);
            for (DataNode node : row.getRowData()) {
                put.add(toBytes(colFamilyName), toBytes(node.getNodeName()),
                        toBytes(node.getNodeValue()));
            }
            aTable.put(put);
            arg3.setStatus("xoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxo added another data row to hbase");
            row = fileParser.getNextRow();
        }
        aTable.flushCommits();
        arg3.setStatus("xoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxo Finished adding data to hbase");

    } finally {
        if (aTable != null) {
            aTable.close();
        }

        if (admin != null) {
            admin.close();
        }
    }

    arg2.collect(new LongWritable(10), new Text("something"));
    arg3.setStatus("xoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoadded some dummy data to the collector");
}
```

As you could see around the end that I am writing some dummy data to collection in the end (10, 'something') and I see hundreds of rows of this data in the _success file after the job has terminated.
I can't identify why the mapper code is restarted multiple times over and over instead of running just once. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using `JobConf.setNumMapTasks(1)` is just saying to hadoop that you wish to use 1 mapper, if possible, unlike the `setNumReduceTasks`, which actually defines the number that you specified.

That's why more mappers are run and you observe all these numbers.

For more details, please read [this post](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces).